# Drop down menu using Perl/Tk code?

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit, perltk

I am new to Perl/Tk and just want to know how I can use a drop down menu in a Perl/Tk-based GUI and how to populate it? Can anyone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 4):

Every Perl/Tk installation has the `widget` demonstration program installed. Just run it; you will find some menu demonstrations under the "Menus" section. I recommend the 2nd item here (titled "As above, but using Perl/Tk -menuitems"). All demonstrations have a "See Code" button for displaying the source code.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a code fragment ([source](http://www.perltk.de/tk_widgets/wtk_optionmenu.html)):

```
use Tk;
use Tk::Optionmenu;

# have some variables
my ($var, $tvar);

# create a drop down menu
my $opt = $mw->Optionmenu(
-options => [[jan=>1], [feb=>2], [mar=>3], [apr=>4]],
-command => sub { print "got: ", shift, "\n" },
-variable => \$var,
-textvariable => \$tvar
)->pack(-side => 'left', -anchor => 'n',);

# populate with some values unless done during initialisation
$opt->addOptions([may=>5],[jun=>6],[jul=>7],[aug=>8]);
```

Answer (score 0):

[TkDocs](http://www.tkdocs.com/) have a nice [Menus](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/menus.html) section (this is not **Tk** but **Tkx** code but this should help)